# Android Material Desin

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, android-layout

my app crashes due to <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout> while working my login page.
Is there any way to fix other than updating dependencies or style. Thanks

my app crashes due to <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout> while working my login page.
Is there any way to fix other than updating dependencies or style. Thanks

Comment: Please check your theme once .

Comment: Add your crash log here

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without any stacktrace.

Most probable answer is you are missing material dependency in the build.gradle file.

Also it is recommended to use AndroidX libraries with material ui.

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
  }
```